# EntityFramework using linq is slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am  trying to get my entities with just some of them child ( one ), but my request is very slow.

My class are :

- 'circuit' : contains list of 'etape'
- 'etape' : contains list of 'question'

I want to filter my circuit, with some geoposition from the first etape of each circuit, and get all the circuit entities who match my filters but only with the first etape of my circuit. ( So the etape of my filtered circuit with `numEtape == 1`).
I want only the first etape because it can be 10,20,30.. etapes per circuit, so to reduce the latence of my query.

This is my query right now and it can be very slow with only 20 000 circuit to filter. ( but with X etape, which etape have Y questions ..)

```
var x = db.circuit.Include("etape").Include("etape.question")
    .Where(
        c => c.etape.Count() >= 2 &&
        c.enabled &&
        !circuitsAfficher.Contains(c.id) &&
        (
            c.etape.Where(e => e.numEtape == 1).FirstOrDefault().posLat > xbottom &&
            c.etape.Where(e => e.numEtape == 1).FirstOrDefault().posLat < xtop
        ) &&
        (
            c.etape.Where(e => e.numEtape == 1).FirstOrDefault().posLong < yright &&
            c.etape.Where(e => e.numEtape == 1).FirstOrDefault().posLong > yleft
        )
    )
    .Select(p => new
        {
            circuit = p,
            etape = p.etape.Where(c => c.numEtape == 1)
        }).ToList();
```

EDIT : New code thanks to @Ivan Stoev, working

```
 listFiltred = db.circuit.AsNoTracking().Where(
                c => c.etape.Count() >= 2 &&
                c.enabled &&
                !circuitsAfficher.Contains(c.id) &&
                c.etape.Any(e => e.numEtape == 1 &&
                e.posLat > Xbottom && e.posLat < Xtop &&
                e.posLong < yright && e.posLong > Yleft))                      
                   .Select(p => new CircuitWithEtape
                   {
                       circ = p,
                       firstetape = p.etape.Where(c => c.numEtape == 1).FirstOrDefault()
                   }).ToList();
```

CircuitWithEtape class :

```
   public class CircuitWithEtape
    {
        public circuit circ { get; set; }
        public etape firstetape { get; set; }
    }
```

At this point i have a list of circuit, with all his etape in pair with his first etape ( firstetape).

Comment: the use of `.FirstOrDefault()` and `Count()` is really going to hurt here as you effectively bypass deferred execution and load the entire data graph to resolve those!!

Comment: I can delete the Count() use, but how can i filter my circuit with a condition on it's first etape children ?

Comment: Does `numEtape == 1` match single etape per circuit? Or it can match more than one?

Comment: There is only one etape where etape.numEtape == 1 per circuit

Comment: because you are selecting the whole circuit entity (which then will have all etapes in there) `filtred.Select(a => a.circuit).ToList();`. At this point `a.etape` should only be 1.

Comment: To fix it, you will either need to create a new class which will be used in place for anonymous and return a list of that. Or do `filtred.Select(a => {a.circuit.etape = a.etape; return a.circuit;}}).ToList();` But beware, if you have change tracking enabled and you call SaveChanges, this will delete the other `etape`s.

Comment: You could also project the anonymous into a new circuit (making it disconnected from EF) `filtred.Select(a => { var res = a.circuit.clone(); res.etape = a.etape; return res;}).ToList();`

Comment: I edited my post, i use a class, but i still have all the etape in my circuit, and i don't know if it's problematic or not

Comment: Your circuit will do because of you're include. EF does not allow you to retrieve partial entity lists. Hence that if you want to only have one, you will have to clone your circuit and/or overwrite the `circuit.etape` property. If you don't clone, your circuit will be still attached to the DbContext, and as you essentially removed all the other `etape`s EF will see it as this relationship no longer exists and attempt to remove that relationship when you call SaveChanges by default, unless you specify you don't want to track the circuits. So be careful

Comment: Oh okay, Thanks for your answer dude ! Very usefull ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all `c.etape.Where(e => e.numEtape == 1).FirstOrDefault()` based conditions (which I suspect generate a subquery per each condition) with single [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338(v=vs.110).aspx) based condition:

```
.Where(
    c => c.etape.Count() >= 2 &&
    c.enabled &&
    !circuitsAfficher.Contains(c.id) &&
    c.etape.Any(e => e.numEtape == 1 &&
        e.posLat > xbottom && e.posLat < xtop &&
        e.posLong < yright && e.posLong > yleft)
)
```

which should generate single `EXISTS (subquery)` condition inside the main query.

**EDIT:** Looking at the final query, the following might be even better:

```
listFiltred = 
    (from c in db.circuit.AsNoTracking()
         .Where(c => c.etape.Count() >= 2 && 
             c.enabled &&
             !circuitsAfficher.Contains(c.id))
     from e in c.etape
         .Where(e => e.numEtape == 1 &&
             e.posLat > Xbottom && e.posLat < Xtop &&
             e.posLong < yright && e.posLong > Yleft)
     select new CircuitWithEtape
     {
         circ = c,
         firstetape = e
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: It seems FAR better ! I will test it tonight when i have access to my project, i will keep you in touch, thank you !

Comment: You mean the `Select` part? Sure, you can use whatever you like there, my answer was targeting only the `Where` clause.

Comment: @Furtiro But you can also try the edited answer, I expect it to produce better and faster SQL.

Comment: Your query isn't working in my project .. The syntax is not right !

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't test it because have no data classes. Just trying to make it better, you can always use the working one. What error are you getting?

Comment: It's working ! Thanks ! I have to make a double request for my other filters but np :)